# How to access the value of an ASPxTextBox from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Suppose I have an DevExpress ASPxTextBox whose id is "instrument". I want to access the value of the text box at client side. So I need to write a javascript.

If it was a normal asp text box, I could have accessed the text box by writing code like 
`var instrumentElement = document.getElementById('<%=instrument.ClientID%>')` 
But the same approach is not working for the DevExpress's Text Box.

How can I access an ASPxTextBox ? I am using Developer Express Version 7.2.

Here is some more thorough code snippet -

```
<div style="display: inline; float: left;">
    <dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="InstrumentQuantity" runat="server" Width="170px">
    </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
</div>

<div style="display: inline; float: left;" onclick="incOrDecQty(0);">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="decrementQuantity" runat="server" 
            Height="16px" Width="16px" ImageUrl="~/images/left.png" 
            AlternateText="Decrease Quantity" PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0);"/>
</div>

<div onclick="incOrDecQty(1);">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="incrementQuantity" runat="server" 
            AlternateText="Increase Quantity" ImageUrl="~/images/right.png" 
            Height="16px" Width="16px" PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0);" />
</div>
```

That was the ASP Code. The corresponding Javascript is as follows :

```
function incOrDecQty()
{
    var element = document.getElementById('<%=InstrumentQuantity.ClientID%>');
    var lotSize = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=LotSize.ClientID%>')
        .innerHTML, 10);
    var currentValue = parseInt(element.value,10);

    if(arguments[0] == 1)
        currentValue += lotSize;
    else if((currentValue - lotSize) >= 0 )
        currentValue -= lotSize;

    element.value= currentValue;            
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the ClientInstanceName property on the AspxTextBox.

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="InstrumentQuantity" 
 runat="server" Width="170px" 
 ClientInstanceName="MyTextBox"> 
</dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

ClientSide:

```
function DoSomething()
{
    var theText = MyTextBox.GetValue(); //GetValue() is the DevExpress clientside function

    MyTextBox.SetValue('this is the value i want to use'); //Sets the text

}
```

The devexpress documentation has some pretty good info on their client side scripts. Go to this [link](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=ASPxEditors), click on Reference, then click on DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.Scripts on the menu.

Comment: Just realized that GetValue() client function might not have been around in your version. If it's not, you can try MyTextBox.GetText().

Comment: I hate the `ClientInstanceName` stuff. It works reliably only for primitive non-nested controls .. I would recommend using a ClientID lookup instead. (All DX controls "add" themselves to `window` by their ClientId: `window[theClientId].SetText(..)`)

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the Client Side methods and events on the ASPxTextBox.

http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=ASPxEditors/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientTextBox_ctortopic.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the third party textbox does not make use of the ClientID. You might try UniqueID, though this may not be a globally acceptable fix (might not work in all browsers).

Comment: ClientID should work with the ASPxTextBox control. The product documentation indicates that it is inherited from TextBox and left alone. If the approach is not working, I would suggest there is something else in there that is preventing it. Perhaps a more thorough code snippet might help?

Answer (score 0):

This method of getting the client-side DevExpress ASPxClientTextBox worked for me:

```
var dxc = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("ASPxTextBoxClientInstanceName");
```

Based on solution from:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251251/