# JavaScript dynamic variable Method call

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress-mvc

I have to use dynamic naming for DevExpress MVC DropDownEdit element, because I use the partialview multiple times on a view.
I try to use the following JavaScript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textSeparator = ";";
    function UpdateText(listBox, args) {
        var listBoxName = listBox.name;
        var locDropDown = document.getElementById("printOutDropDown" + listBoxName);
        if (locDropDown != null && locDropDown !== undefined) {
            alert('I am in');
            locDropDown['SetText'](listBox.GetSelectedItem().text);
            locDropDown['HideDropDown']();
        }
       
    }
```

Where SetText and HideDropDown are DevExpress specific functions
[SetText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientButton_SetTexttopic)
[HideDropDown](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientDropDownEditBase_HideDropDowntopic)

I always get the error: Object doesn't support property or method 'SetText'
I tried tu use:

```
locDropDown.SetText(...
locDropDown().SetText(...
locDropDown()['SetText']...
```

Nothing is working. Could somebody please give me advise, how to solve this Problem?

Additional info:
1) When I give the Control a specific Name and just use it once, then everything works fin
2) The Alert is raised, so locDropDown is definitly not null or undefined.

THX

Comment: Hey again. I found a solution, but don't understand, why the eval() is working...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateText(listBox, args) {
        var listBoxName = listBox.name;
        var locDropDownName = "printOutDropDown" + listBoxName;
        var locDropDown = document.getElementById("printOutDropDown" + listBoxName);
        if (locDropDown != null && locDropDown !== undefined) {
            eval(locDropDownName).SetText(listBox.GetSelectedItem().text);
            eval(locDropDownName).HideDropDown();
        }
       
    }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `locDropDown` is a DevExpress control.

The way to get the control is to use the client control collection functions:

```
var locDropDown = 
ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("printOutDropDown" + listBoxName)
```

Then you should be able to use the DevExpress JavaScript functions against that control (such as `SetText()` etc.)